# Three.js collision detection not working with textures

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures, collision-detection

I used raycasting to make a full collision detection system for my scene that has a box in it. The collisions work fine if my box has colored materials, but not if the materials contain textures. [You can see my full code here. This line checks for intersections.`var intersections = raycaster.intersectObjects(objects, true);`](https://pastebin.com/UtY2VkC3). 
 According to the raycaster docs, setting the second parameter to true will check for all descendants, but doing it didn't make a difference. [Here](https://pre00.deviantart.net/717b/th/pre/f/2012/345/d/0/crate_generator_by_dactilardesign-d5np5b6.jpg) is a texture you can use if you rename it to 'texture.jpg'. I think you have to use the texture to see it not working. On line 212 you can switch to g3colour to see the working demo. I have no idea why it doesn’t work with textures. Currently, the right-most side is solid, but all other sides are not. Do you know what my problem is?

Any help is appreciated, thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a few minutes to look through the Help Center, specifically [`How do I ask a good question?`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be sure to include and supporting code and errors with your question. Also, consider creating a [`Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) using [snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). **It is preferred that code be embedded in your question, rather than linked, for when (not if) the link no longer works.**

Comment: @3ft Do you mean raycaster is not working with material arrays? Try the latest three.js release.

Comment: @WestLangley yes!!!!!!!!! That was the problem. It works fine with r95. Thank you so so so much, I always thought it was a problem on my end and never would have thought to update the build.